# What can I use for playing video instead of Android MediaPlayer class?

Tags: android

I need to play several videos on Android simultaneosly. I run tests with Android MediaPlayer class on several devices. Most of devices can play only 4 videos simultaneously.
What can I use for playing video instead of Android MediaPlayer class? It is neccesary for me to pass Surface to player, and then change frame textures with using opengl shaders in order to play video with alpha channel.

Comment: How are you managing the stream? 4 videos at once on a mobile device isn't exactly bad, how many are you trying to run?

Comment: I tried 5 videos. 4 videos are enough for me. But sometimes one of this 4 videos doesn't start.